# aws cloudformation deploy fails on adding --tags

Tags: jenkins, aws-cloudformation

I tried to run `aws cloudformation deploy` with `--tags` option, but have the following error:

```
Error in jenkins pipeline console:
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

push                                     | register                                
deregister                               | install
```

Full command:

```
sh "aws cloudformation deploy --region=us-east-1 --template-file template.yaml --stack-name template-stack --parameter-overrides parameter1=value1 --tags keyname=keyvalue"
```

Cloudformation template is successfully uploaded on removing --tags key=value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you use old version of aws-cli. This [feature](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2324) was merged only in January 2018 (see [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/3106) pull-request). So, please check your version and update if needed.

Comment: Thanks @biruk1230. I was using old version 1.11. Upgrading cli version fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I get the "`aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:`" error with an AWS command, it is usually that I have a parameter name wrong, such as `--template-body` versus `--template-file`, for a `cloudformation deploy`. Try removing any extraneous options first, to whittle down to the problematic option.